# How can I display a custom errorPage and still return 404

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, http-error

There is a routing table that includes

```
 routes.MapRoute("404-PageNotFound", "{*url}", new { controller = "Error", action = "PageNotFound" });
```

The web.config has:

```
<customErrors mode="RemoteOnly">        
   <error statusCode="404" redirect="/Error/PageNotFound" />
</customErrors>
```

The ErrorController gets hit when no Route Matches and the View for errors get rendered using:

```
public ActionResult PageNotFound(ViewModelBase model)
 {
     return View(model);
}
```

The status code for the response is 200, but in this case a 404 is required. Is there a way to return http code 404 and a custome errorpage?

Answer (score 5):

```
public ActionResult PageNotFound(ViewModelBase model)
{
    Response.StatusCode = 404;
    return View(model);
}
```